# "Expected an indented block" in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to read a bag file and I'm only using spaces instead of tab but I get error when I run my python code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import rosbag
bag = rosbag.Bag('2016-06-06-12-57-11.bag')
for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=['/base_scan']):
for (msg.min.ranges[i], msg.max.ranges[i]):
    print("%f " % (msg.ranges[i]))
bag.close()
```

I have 4 spaces before print(...). What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Your `for`-loop is syntactically wrong. What's this loop for?

Comment: I have a file (.bag) in this file there is information of a robot. I want all information of robot's laser scan which is called /base_scan. But I'm not sure how to get these data from this file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content of the outer for-loop also needs to be intended with 4 spaces:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import rosbag
bag = rosbag.Bag('2016-06-06-12-57-11.bag')
for topic, msg, t in bag.read_messages(topics=['/base_scan']):
    for (msg.min.ranges[i], msg.max.ranges[i]):
        print("%f " % (msg.ranges[i]))
bag.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, now I got "invalid syntax" which is because of the second loop!

Comment: What exactly is the second loop supposed to do? Should it over a range of numbers?

Comment: The second loop should take range of numbers (laser data) from min. to max. which is all of them. And then these numbers should be printed ! 

Do I need a line of code in between of second loop and print to increment each range[i] ?

Comment: `for i in range([min], [max]):` should do the trick. Just replace [min] and [max] with the according expressions. Be aware that the min value is inclusive while the max value is exclusiv. This means that `range(3, 7)` will iterate over 3, 4, 5 and 6 but not 7.

Comment: Omit the square brackets so you get `for i in range(msg.min.ranges, msg.max.ranges):` They were there to show you that this part has to be replaced by you. If this works, tell me and I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I get error about attribute! : '_sensor_msgs__LaserScan' object has no attribute 'min'  

I did also delet [] in:

 print("%f " % (msg.ranges))

Comment: This is turning into a new question. Now it is about how to use the rosbag library (which I never used and don't know at all). You should search for yourself how to get the minimum and maximum index for the ranges attribute. I can't help you with that.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot for helping.